# How to control the file permissions when the netbeans php plugin uploads a file with FTP

Tags: php, netbeans, ftp, file-permissions

Whenever netbeans preforms an ftp upload the files are uploaded with the permissions set to 640. This causes PHP to throw the following error:

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/Library/WebServer/Documents/notes/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

While I can clean it up with a quick `chmod o+r ./*` in the command prompt it causes netbeans to resynchronize the entire project next time I hit run which in turn sets the permissions back to 640.

I need a way to make netbeans upload the files with permissions set to 644.

Answer (score 11):

Make sure the checkbox for "Preserve Remote File Permissions" under Project Properties > Run Configuration is checked, if you want to not change remote file permissions.

Answer (score 3):

I determined that the problem was not with netbeans. It was with `ftpd` on the server.

The fix was to create a file called `ftpd.conf` in `/etc/` and add the following line:

```
umask all 022
```

Answer (score 3):

In your vsftp.conf file, look for this:

```
# Default umask for local users is 077. You may wish to change this to 022,
local_umask=022
```

Then, un-comment / adjust as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make a little easier if you are tired like I was. All the other answer where a rabbit hole and didn't work for me.

[image]

Comment: This works for me perfekt... I had always a permission change von 755 to 644 after editing and save.