# Netbeans remote file permissions. chmod from within Netbeans?

Tags: php, netbeans, chmod

When working with a project, a'la "PHP application from remote server"
The file properties I am offered, when I right-click->properties on files, relate only to the local properties.

Is it possible to modify file permissions on the remote files from within Netbeans somehow?

Currently for each new file I create, I have to *manually* chmod it, once, via ssh. I'd like to know if it's possible to do that from within Netbeans. With a plugin perhaps?

And yes I am aware of the 'preserve remote file permissions' setting and I do use it.
Google has many results about that feature but none pertinent to what I am asking ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in NetBeans. I use FireFTP in FireFox for changing file permissions on remote servers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [dnotify](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dnotify) on your server to modify the file permissions every time you change a file.

> dnotify -M -r -b /var/www -e chmod -R 755 /var/www

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, no you can't.

However, you should be able (if you have access) to [change the default permissions given to files by your FTP server](https://superuser.com/search?q=set%20default%20file%20permissions%20FTP%20server), which will resolve this problem.

It would be worth checking to see if another FTP client gives you the same problem, whereby you need to SSH in to chmod the file before you can use it. If this does happen, then it's most likely a configuration problem with your FTP server. [A bit like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711918/how-to-control-the-file-permissions-when-the-netbeans-php-plugin-uploads-a-file).